# Read Next Node in XML (Linq to XML C#)

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document (without attributes) that is setup like this:

```
<variables>
    <variable>
        <name>Name_Value</name>
        <value>Value of Entry</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>Name_Value2</name>
        <value>Value of Entry2</value>
    </variable>
</variables>
```

I have used LINQ to XML to get a list of all the `<name>` values in the document. These name values are displayed in a listbox control in alphabetical order (which is *not* the order of the names in the XML document).

When an item is selected in the listbox, I want to pass the name of the item to a method that will search the XML document for that value within the `<name>` node. Once found, I want to find the next node (i.e., the `<value>` node) and return it's value as a string.

I've tried all sorts of things to get this information, but apparently I don't know enough about LINQ to XML to get this work. Can only provide a solution for this?

Comment: Isn't there a way to set up the dropdown so that it displays `name` but the actual value of each item is `value`.  If so, you may not have to go digging through the XML document each time a selection is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from v in xdoc.Descendants("variable")
            where (string)v.Element("name") == name
            select (string)v.Element("value");
```

This Linq query will return `IEnumerbale<string>` of value elements, which matched your name. If you sure there should be no more than one variable with specified name

```
string value = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Or in single query:

```
string value =  xdoc.Descendants("variable")
                    .Where(v => (string)v.Element("name") == name)
                    .Select(v => (string)v.Element("value"))
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked just great. No, there will never be a duplicate variable value. The program that makes the XML doesn't allow duplicate entries, and manually putting in a duplicate entry crashes said program (not one I created).

Comment: @EustaceMonk good! Then I'd go with last one sample (I like method syntax more, when single or first result is required)

Answer (score 0):

I think an approache that uses XPath is easier to read :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = XElement.Parse(@"<variables>
    <variable>
        <name>Name_Value</name>
        <value>Value of Entry</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>Name_Value2</name>
        <value>Value of Entry2</value>
    </variable>
</variables>");

        Console.WriteLine(
                      GetVariableValue(xml, "Name_Value")
                ); 
        Console.WriteLine(
                      GetVariableValue(xml, "Name_Value2")
                ); 

    }

        public static string GetVariableValue(XElement xml, string variableName)
        {
             return xml.XPathSelectElement("variables/variable[name='" + variableName + "']/value").Value;
        }
}
```